# wrap and unwrap styled text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tryed to mark text with js, i select text and then hit button that wrap the selected area with span tag - but if i select area that half of it have style, it's remove the style from the selected area and put the span.

This is my code:

```
function markText() {
    var sel, range;

    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();

        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            selectedText = range.toString();
            range.deleteContents();
            var n = document.createElement('span');
            n.className = "Mark";

            n.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedText));
            range.insertNode(n);
        }
    }
}

function removeMarks() {
    $(".Mark").each(function () {
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    });
}
```

Example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liron_e/g7QTp/

If you try to mark "is some" you will see the problem..

I also want that if i select text from 2 lines or more in each div it will create that span tag in the right place.

In addition i want to remove the span tag when i click the other button and go back to the previous style.

Comment: I guess you mean wrap and not warp...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rh5hk/1/ check this

Comment: it's not helpful... :(

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, then use jQuery and avoid stuff like `n.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedText));`

Comment: what you asked is brilliant question which is limited by many things [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/Rh5hk/4/) this will give you idea how to get html tag from selected text and retain it for highlighting and it will also [show you another limitation](http://jsfiddle.net/Rh5hk/5/).In first example select the bold text and in the second case select across div i have added content of your fiddle to mine so the alert box clearly display the html selected the problem i am trying to highlight is that browser automatically makes the selected html valid so even if select opening tag only

Comment: Closing tag will be added to it automatically so other part will be left

Answer (score 0):

first `var n = document.createElement('span');  // create object`

then `document.appendchiild(n) // put n into HTML-DOM`

then `n.className = "Mark";  // property also in HTML-DOM, property of SPAN tag ?`

```
document.createTextNode(selectedText)  // must return a pointer for n.appendChild()
```

do not forget:  var `n` is local an not global.